# How to avoid ORM situation during class design?

Tags: php, orm

Currently, I am working on a project of an online service provider.But I am really confused on class designing.

I have tables for actors like `admin`, `customer`, `agent` and tables for data storage like `city`, `services`, `category`, `sub-category`, `gender`.

I have created classes for the `admin`, `customer` and `agent`. But should I create classes for `city`, `services`, `category`, etc. tables which look like an ORM design as well?

Is it good to have one class for each table in a database? If not then please explain how to avoid this situation? Can I use enum or ArrayList instead of class for data storage?

Updated:- I want to perform CRUD operation for `city`, `services`, `category`, `sub-category`, `gender`

Comment: Confusing tables with classes is a bad idea and so are ORMs. To avoid that, use OOP for system services that encapsulate sets of data, not individual rows.

Comment: @reaanb can you give example on this?

Comment: You didn't say what your system is supposed to do. You might have a CityForm and a CityServicesReport talking to CityRepository talking to the DBMS. CityForm might talk to other repositories to get data for lookup lists. CityServicesReport might talk to a ReportBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

What is a class, basically it will contain the attribute and behavior called the functions.
If you really have too many reusable functions and attribute better to use a class or else not.
Example,
I have class Vehicle so I know it can have following property

```
 Class Vehicle {
  String color;
  int tier;
  function setTier(){
   }
  function getTier{}{
   }
 }
 Class Bike implements Vehicle{
   // you can use the attribute and function of the Class vehicle 
   //as it is parent class.
  }
```

In such case, you can create different classes based on your need.

Comment: But if I don't want to create a separate class for each table. Can you give examples of both sides? Can I use `enum` or `array list` instead of a `class`?